# Adding version requirements in OSGI capability

Tags: java, osgi, requirements

Does OSGI capabilities support versioning and how does it work? Say I have a module with the following declared:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: my-module
Implementation-Version: 1.8.1-qualifier
Provide-Capability: org.foo.dependency;nameId="my-module",version="1.8.1-qualifier"
```

Would I then be able to add this require to get the module above?

```
Require-Capability: org.foo.dependency;filter:="&(nameId=my-module)(version>=1.8)"
```

Is there also a way to leverage `Implementation-Version` on the manifest if it's already specified in the provider module? I see references to `osgi.wiring.bundle` [here](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.namespaces.html#i1773242). Would I be able to do this instead on the require:

```
Require-Capability: org.foo.dependency;filter:="(nameId=my.module)",osgi.wiring.bundle;filter:="(bundle-version>=1.8)"
```

Appreciate any pointers on the subject matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.8.1-qualifier` is not a valid [OSGi version](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.module.html#i2655136). `1.8.1.qualifier` is a valid OSGi version.

`&(nameId=my-module)(version>=1.8)` is not a valid [OSGi filter expression](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.filtersyntax). You need to surround with parenthesis. `(&(nameId=my-module)(version>=1.8))`

You cannot use `Implementation-Version`, but you can use `Bundle-Version`.

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: my-module
Bundle-Version: 1.8.1.qualifier

Require-Capability: osgi.wiring.bundle;filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.bundle=my-module)(bundle-version>=1.8))"
```

See https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.namespaces.html#framework.namespaces.osgi.wiring.bundle.